# SalesForce: Can you open a text field with a custom button

Tags: button, salesforce, field

I am building a custom button and I have this so far:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/8.0/connection.js")}

var lead = new sforce.SObject("Lead");
lead.id = "{!Lead.Id}";
lead.OwnerId = "ID";
lead.Status = "STATUS";

var result = sforce.connection.update([lead]);

if (result[0].getBoolean("success"))
{
    // Refresh window
    window.location.reload();
}
else
{
    alert("Error saving lead");
}
```

This all works perfectly and makes the changes I desire, but what I also want to happen is when the button is clicked, and before anything is saved, I want the:

```
lead.Reason__c
```

Text field to pop up, like it would if you double clicked it, so that the user can fill in a reason for clicking the button

I have tried code like:

```
lead.Reason__c.open
lead.Reason__c.edit
```

But have had no luck and am pretty much just stabbing in the dark with this.

I hope someone can help,
Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have one field, you do not need a form, I would recommend you use javascript's prompt box and if it returns something other than null (null -> user clicked cancel) do your magic

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/8.0/connection.js")}

var reason = prompt("Enter reason", "");
if (reason != null) {
    var lead = new sforce.SObject("Lead");
    lead.id = "{!Lead.Id}";
    lead.OwnerId = "ID";
    lead.Status = "STATUS";
    lead.Reason__c = reason;

...
}
```

PS: I would also recommend using a "fresher" ajax toolkit than 8.0 :) we are at 24.0 now. I doubt they'll obsolete the old ones but you never know.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip about the new toolkit! i will update that! Thanks for your help, I will look into sorting out a solution through a similar method.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to truly simulate a double-click is by dispatching a double-click event to the element; [this page](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents) has an excellent reference on how to do that. I can confirm that you can create a custom button that dispatches a double-click to an SFDC edit field and it acts as if the user double-clicked the field themselves. Quick and dirty example:

```
var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
evObj.initMouseEvent( 'dblclick', true, true, window, 1, 12, 345, 7, 220, false, false, true, false, 0, null );
document.getElementById('lea13_ilecell').dispatchEvent(evObj);
```

However, that's not going to be a sound approach for you because once you double-click a field, as you know, the "Save" and "Cancel" buttons are rendered to the user with no ability to override their behavior in the manner you need to. You could hack around this with some jQuery magic, but I'd recomment mmix's approach, it's much more sound. If your requirements expand to something beyond a single text field, you may need to incorporate some fancy dynamic HTML/CSS dialog boxes, or VisualForce, but based on what you need, the prompt approach is the simplest answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help! I will look into this, all I need is for the text field to be opened automatically, then the user can enter what they need to and then save. Once again, thanks!

Comment: Cool, well if that's all you're trying to do, this may be the way to go. You'll need to replace "lea13_ilecell" with the HTML ID of the field cell you are trying to edit (view source on the edit page to get this; bear in mind that custom fields may change ID from environment to environment).